# can not move picture to the file path

Tags: php

```
function change_profile_image($session_uid, $file_temp, $file_extn) {

    $file_path ='../dist/img/profile/'.substr(md5(time()), 0, 32).".". $file_extn; //substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) display 10 character in random

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_path,$file_temp)){
            //move file in temporary location
            mysql_query("UPDATE `qaxissim`.`qaxisusers` SET `imagepath` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($file_path)."' WHERE `u_id` = ".(int)$session_uid);
            header("Location: ?setting");   

            //mysql_real_escape_string($file_path)
    }else{
        echo 'fail';
        exit();
    }   
  } 
}
```

fail

Comment: Where is `$file_path_old` defined?

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php),

```
move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination ) : bool
```

$filename -> source file.

As per my observation,

```
move_uploaded_file($file_path,$file_temp)
```

You put source file as destination.

I think `$file_path_old` is `$file_path`. in above code.

Comment: Think it should be `move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path)` - more like an undefined variable error than the names the wrong way round.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually variable file_path.

Comment: it doesn't move the path eventhough I have reversed it

Comment: and.. is the issue solved ? edit your code to change  file_path_old var.

Comment: @JunreyGudia Make sure 1st parameter is source and 2nd is destination.

Answer (score 0):

The **move_uploaded_file()** function moves an uploaded file to a new destination.

> **Note**: This function only works on files uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism.
>
> **Note**: If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.

**Syntax**
move_uploaded_file(file, dest);

In your code i think your passing the newly created image file instead of the destination. Please check. The above given is the syntax and all.